# Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using "InMemoryTokenManager" to tweet messages from my application.

The method  "auth.BeginAuthorize();" returns an exception as "Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.".
Can somebody help me out of this problem.

Thx- Satya

Answer (score 0):

This error message maybe seen when you do not have your Return Url set correctly in your Twitter App that can be found after logging to Twitter here: https://dev.twitter.com/apps

Answer (score 0):

As for me, it was popping out because of checking authorization twice. After removing second call to check authorization, it starts work OK.